# How to tag photos in facebook-api?

Tags: facebook

I wanted to ask if/how is it possible to tag a photo using the FB API (Graph or REST).

I've managed to create an album and also to upload a photo in it, but I stuck on tagging.

I've got the permissions and the correct session key.

My code until now:

```
try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $token = $session['access_token'];//here I get the token from the $session array
    $album_id = $album[0];

    //upload photo
    $file= 'images/hand.jpg';
    $args = array(
        'message' => 'Photo from application',
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    //returns the id of the photo you just uploaded
    print_r(json_decode($data,true));

    $search = array('{"id":', "}");
    $delete = array("", "");

    // picture id call with $picture
    $picture = str_replace($search, $delete, $data);

    //here should be the photos.addTag, but i don't know how to solve this
    //above code works, below i don't know what is the error / what's missing

    $json = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/photos.addTag?pid='.urlencode($picture).'&tag_text=Test&x=50&y=50&access_token='.urlencode($token);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $json;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
} catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);
}
```

I really searched a long time, if you know something that might help me, please post it here :)
Thanks for all your help,
Camillo

Comment: Were you able to make it working through test console? What error does it return? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.addTag

Comment: It returns "121 Invalid photo id"

I've searched a whole day only for this, but it seems that the method is gone/broken/deprecated...

If anyone knows a solution, It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Camillo

Comment: It doesn't work at all, neither by direct call from browser, nor by test-console, nor by curl...

I am very sad about this, i very liked the idea to integrate this into my app :(


Thanks btw for your answer,
Camillo

Comment: And you are using a user unique photo id (string, not number), right?

Comment: what would be an example pid? I've tried both: "1102901671" and "1425341".

Would be awesome if you could help me fix that :)

Thanks so much,
Camillo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photo id is unique for every user and looks like two numbers joined by underscore in the middle.

Getting this id is a bit tricky.

You can get it by running FQL on [`photo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo) table but you need to provide album id which is also user unique. You can get album id from [`album`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album) table but you need to provide owner userid.

For example we have CocaCola user with userid 40796308305. To get photo ids from this user we can run FQL:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner="40796308305")
```

(you can run it in a test console on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query))

This would return our photo ids:

```
[
  {
    "pid": "40796308305_2298049"
  },
  {
    "pid": "40796308305_1504673"
  },
  {
    "pid": "40796308305_2011591"
  },
  ...
]
```

I didn't work with photos much, maybe you don't have to go through all this process to get photo id, it might be some simple algorithm like `<OWNER_ID>_<PHOTO_ID>`. But try to get your photo id from FQL and see if tagging would work. If it does maybe you will be able to skip FQL part and build photo id from existing data you have.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have tried with a sample photo, only with the test console. It worked when i did pid= 40796308305_2011591

Basically I have no idea of FQL, how to call it?

And what's the album id of a application-photo-album?

Hope you can help me finish this :)

Greetz,
Camillo

Comment: @Camillo You can read about FQL here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ and play with it in a test console from the link in the answer which would show you how your request url should look like and where to send it.

Answer (score 9):

Hey,
you can tag the Picture directly on the Upload with the GRAPH API,
see the example below:
This Method creates an array for the tag information, in this examples the method becomes an array with Facebook user Ids:

```
private function makeTagArray($userId) {
    foreach($userId as $id) {
          $tags[] = array('tag_uid'=>$id, 'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y);
          $x+=10;
          $y+=10;
      }
    $tags = json_encode($tags);
    return $tags;
}
```

Here are the arguments for the call of the GRAPH API to upload an picture:

```
$arguments = array(
                    'message' => 'The Comment on this Picture',
                    'tags'=>$this->makeTagArray($this->getRandomFriends($userId)),
                    'source' => '@' .realpath( BASEPATH . '/tmp/'.$imageName),
            );
```

And here is the Method for the GRAPH API call:

```
    public function uploadPhoto($albId,$arguments) {
    //https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
    try {

       $fbUpload = $this->facebook->api('/'.$albId.'/photos?access_token='.$this->facebook->getAccessToken(),'post', $arguments);
       return $fbUpload;
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $e;
       // var_dump($e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The argument $albId contains an ID from an Facebook Album.

And if you want to Tag an existing Picture from an Album you can user this Method:
At First we need the correct picture ID from the REST API, In this example we need the Name from an Album wich the Application has create or the user wich uses this Application.
The Method returns The Picture ID From the last Uploaded Picture of this Album:

```
public function getRestPhotoId($userId,$albumName) {
     try {
        $arguments = array('method'=>'photos.getAlbums',
                            'uid'=>$userId
            );
       $fbLikes = $this->facebook->api($arguments);
       foreach($fbLikes as $album) {

           if($album['name'] == $albumName) {
               $myAlbId = $album['aid'];
           }
       }
       if(!isset($myAlbId))
           return FALSE;
       $arguments = array('method'=>'photos.get',
                            'aid'=>$myAlbId
            );
       $fbLikes = $this->facebook->api($arguments);
       $anz = count($fbLikes);
       var_dump($anz,$fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid']);
       if(isset($fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid']))
           return $fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid'];
       else
           return FALSE;
       //var_dump($fbLikes[$anz-1]['pid']);
       //return $fbLikes;
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $e;
       // var_dump($e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you have the correct picture ID From the REST API and you can make your REST API CALL to tag this Picture $pid is the Picture from the Method getRestPhotoId and $tag_uid is an Facebook userId:

```
    $json = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/photos.addTag?pid='.$pid.'&tag_uid='.$userId.'&x=50&y=50&access_token='.$this->facebook->getAccessToken();

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $json;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

And this line is very important:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
you must youse CUROPT_GET instead of CUROPT_POST to add a Tag throw the REST API.

I Hope this helps you.

Best wishes Kay from Stuttart

Comment: i'm getting **Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id** using your code, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, the problem is that when you use curl to send the array the post function will not send the array correctly, it was sending just "Array" that it was why the graph API complained about tags being an array. To solve that I did the following:

```
$data = array(array('tag_uid' => $taguser,
                  'x' => rand() % 100,
                  'y' => rand() % 100
                  ));

$data = json_encode($data);

$photo_details = array(
 'message'=> $fnames,
 'tags' => $data
);
```

Now I just send using curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $photo_details);
```