# photo tagging problem - Facebook/Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code dont works, the upload is done properly but tagging is failed :(
It shows **fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id thrown**

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$album_details = array(
 'message'=> 'Description',
 'name'=> 'Name'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
$photo_details = array(
 'message'=> 'Photo Description',
 'tags'=> makeTagArray($friendsID),
);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath('img/'.$img_name);
// $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$create_album['id'].'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$create_album['id'].'/photos?access_token='.$facebook->getAccessToken(),'post', $photo_details);

function makeTagArray($userId) {
 foreach($userId as $id) {
      $tags[] = array('tag_uid'=>$id, 'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y);
      $x+=50;
      $y+=50;
  }
 $tags = json_encode($tags);
 return $tags;
}
```

**Other necessary info**

```
'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,status_update,user_photos'
```

I also tried this but did not worked, it shows **data[]**

```
$x=5;
 $response='';
 for ($i=0;$i<count($friendsName);$i++)
 {
  $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$upload_photo['id']."/tags/".$friendsID[$i]."?access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken()."&amp;x=".$x."&amp;y=80&amp;method=POST";
  $response = $response.file_get_contents($post_url);
  $x = $x + 53;
 }
```

Examle **$post_url** for a single person, then i run this in a loop for all the persons

`https://graph.facebook.com/Pic_ID/tags/620949133?access_token=Access_Token|2.AQDOMdHNge0UCXG6.3600.1307613600.1-100001916529381|lCYzRYy9YPJvy1WBqkuoGVWvd50&x=5&y=80&method=POST`

Shows

`{

   "error" : {

      "type": "OAuthException",

      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."

   }
}`

*i've changed some value intentionally*

Comment: The prblem was not with code, the GRAPH API was having issues, now it's solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this permission to the required permissions: `user_photos`

Comment: still shows **Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id**

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to request the publish_stream permission.
2. You need to make multiple requests, 1 for each facebook user/page you are tagging.

To make the request you need to image id in facebook and the user id.
Post to either PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID or PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID, with the X & Y co-ordinates as variables.

See the official documentation here (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) for more guidance.

Comment: @sourav can you provide the example post_url you are trying to use, that will make it easier to see how you're getting this error.

Comment: @sourav does this code successfully upload the photo in question? It appears from the URL you added that you are not getting the 'photo_id' or pic_id as it appears in your URL. Getting the photo ID is described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484159/how-to-tag-photos-in-facebook-api it requires the use of FQL in addition to the GraphAPI REST functions

Comment: It successfully uploads the Image to the album, here is the App id **232817533399152**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible but you can give it a try. Try first to upload the Photo. Then get the picture's ID from the uploaded photo and then add the tags to the uploaded photo.