# How to optimized the following tag (php code - graph api)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
 foreach($friends_array as $user) {
    $argstag = array('to' => $user);
    $argstag['x'] = $locations_x[$i];
    $argstag['y'] = $locations_y[$i];
    $datatag = $facebook->api('/' . $photo_id . '/tags', 'post', $argstag);
    $i++;
 }
```

Instead of doing this in loop (multiple api requests), Is there a way to do it in a single api request?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484159/how-to-tag-photos-in-facebook-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code works for me provided array $friends have less equal 50 friends:

```
$tags = array();
 foreach ($friends as $friend)
         {
            $tag = array();
            $tag['tag_uid'] = $friend;
            $tag['x'] = rand() % 100;
            $tag['y'] = rand() % 100;
            $tags[] = $tag;
         }
          $argstag = array(
            'tags' => $tags
          );
          $facebook->api("$photoId/tags","POST", $argstag);
```

Comment: It took long time howerver. "200 OK 17.28s". How long does it take to you? Why it is very slow while tag friends? I am tagging five friends.

Comment: its taking more time for you than usual it seems. I tag 40 random friends and takes around 20-30 sec. also I do it using xmlhttprequest, so it keeps tagging in background and I do not need to wait for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing large amounts of operations at the same time, consider using the [batch request API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).  It lets you perform multiple tasks (up to 50) at the same time.

Here's an example on how you could theoretically use it:

```
$batches = array();
$i = $b = 0;
foreach($friends_array as $user) {
 $argstag = array('to' => $user);
 $argstag['x'] = $locations_x[$i];
 $argstag['y'] = $locations_y[$i];

 // If we've reached the batch limit, create a new batch request.
 if ($i == 50) {
    $b++;
    $i = 0;
 }

 // Single batch request.
 $batches["$b"][] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => '/' . $photo_id . '/tags',
    'body' => 'to=' . $user . '&x=' . $locations_x[$i] . '&y=' . $locations_y[$i]
 );

 $i++;
}

if (!empty($batches)) {
  foreach ($batches AS $key => $batch) {
    $b = json_encode($batch);
    $res = $facebook->api('?batch=' . urlencode($b), 'POST');
    // Facebook populates $res with the response.
  }
}
```

This isn't tested, but hopefully that's helpful.  It may not be what you're looking for for that, but it's worth noting if you have a large number of requests you need to send to Facebook's servers.

Comment: I tried your coding. But it is also taking very long time to tag friends. But without tag, it is very quick in uploading the photo to facebook. I tag 5 friends.